# reading a csv file to parse dates

Tags: python, csv

I have a .csv file that contain these data :

```
equipement,"144444444"
Date,"Time","measure"
16/09/2016,"07:15:00","16.47777"
16/09/2016,"07:30:00","15.44454"
16/09/2016,"07:45:00","16.21114"
```

I run a python code on this file, my objective is to have something like this as an output:

```
"measure","20160916071500","16.47777"
"measure","20160916073000","15.44454"
"measure","20160916074500","16.21114"
```

Here is my code :

```
import csv
import sys
import os
import re
import fnmatch
import csv
from dateutil.parser import parse as parseDate
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta


    file = open("myfile.csv", 'rt')
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(reader)
    rows = list(reader)
    firstline = rows[0]
    header = firstline[2]
    print header
    for row in rows:
        next(reader)
        print rows[0]
        if "".join(row).strip() != "":
            chaine = str(row[0]+row[1])
            #print chaine
            date = chaine[:10] + " " + chaine[11:]
            #print date
            index = parseDate(date)
            index = str(index).replace('-','')
            index = str(index).replace(':','')
            index = str(index).replace(' ','')
            data = row[2]
```

My problem is that, I need to do next(reader) to skip the first and the second line in the file, as they don't contain any date. but i get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "t.py", line 19, in <module> next(reader) StopIteration
```

Any idea?

Comment: you haven't posted an error

Comment: The error is : `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 19, in <module>
    next(reader)
StopIteration`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing `rows = list(reader)`, you've already exhausted the `reader` and collected the results in a list called `rows`. Doing `next(reader)` again will then raise `StopIteration`.

It isn't necessary to create the `rows` list, though. You can directly iterate over `reader` using the `for` loop:

```
reader = csv.reader(file)
next(reader)               # skip first line
secondline = next(reader)  # capture second line
header = secondline[2]
for row in reader:         # iterate from third line to the end
    # next(reader) <-- don't do this, the for loop already does it for you
    if "".join(row).strip() != "":
        # ... your code processing row ...
```

Comment: Are you sure you have removed `rows = list(reader)`? Are you sure you have no `next(reader)` inside the for loop? Are you sure your input file has more than one line?

Comment: Yes and I need this code : `rows = list(reader)
    firstline = rows[0]
    header = firstline[2]` to retreive the header that contain the string "measure". Your code works but it is not giving the result I want.

Comment: By doing `firstline = next(reader)` you have already captured the first line and can extract the header from it. You don't need the `rows` list.

Comment: the header is in the second line not the first. I'm still trying to capture it, without using `pandas`

Answer (score 3):

You can solve it with pandas if you will:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('in.csv', skiprows=2, header=None, parse_dates=[[0,1]])
df['dt']=df["0_1"].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))
df['mes'] = pd.Series(["measure"]*len(df), index=df.index)
df[['mes','dt',2]].to_csv('out.csv', quoting=True, index=None,header=None)
```

CSV File:

```
"measure","20160916071500","16.47777"
"measure","20160916073000","15.44454"
"measure","20160916074500","16.21114"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the same desired output using only `two for loops` and some string replacements like this example (i assume your input is called `in.csv`):

```
data = list(k.strip("\n") for k in open("in.csv", 'r'))
mesure = data[1].split(",")[2]
m = list(k.replace('"', "").split(",") for k in data[2:])

final, d =[], ""
for k in m:
    for j in k[:-1]:
        if "/" in j:
            d = '"%s' % "".join(j.split("/")[::-1])
        if ":" in j:
            d += '%s"' % "".join(j.split(":"))
    final.append(",".join([mesure, d,'"%s"' % k[-1:][0]]))

for k in final:
    print(k)
```

Output:

```
"measure","20160916071500","16.47777"
"measure","20160916073000","15.44454"
"measure","20160916074500","16.21114"
```